# OpenGL. Поворот и перемещение 2D-карты

Tags: opengl, 2d

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в одном вопросе.
Кажется что это что-то простое, но самостоятельно разобраться не получается.

В общем? вывожу на экран двумерную карту. Хочу реализовать перемещение по карте и её поворот. Отдельно работает, а вместе... тоже работает, но не так как я хочу :). А хочу я, чтобы карта после перемещения вращалась не относительно своего центра, а относительно той точки, на которую карту переместили. Той, которая располагается в центре экрана.

Если использую вариант:

```
glTranslatef(dX, dY, 0.0);
glRotatef(angle,0,0,1);
```

Происходит перемещение, а вращение происходит относительно центра карты.

Другой вариант:

```
glRotatef(angle,0,0,1); 
glTranslatef(dX, dY, 0.0);
```

Вращение происходит так как мне нужно, но возникает проблема с перемещением. Это хорошо заметно на угле 90 градусов. Я имею повёрнутую на 90 градусов карту, и перемещаясь по оси Х карта перемещается по оси Y и наоборот.

Никак не могу понять, что мне нужно добавить, чтобы всё заработало как нужно.

Comment: Если вы делаете glRotatef, а потом glTranslatef. Смещение в glTranslatef нужно умножить на обратную матрицу повопрота, т.к. при повороте, ваша система координат уже стала другой. В 2Д матрица повопрота довольно проста: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0 А вообще лучше использовать glm и оперировать матрицами https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, то мне нужно сделать приверно следующее:

    float dX1 = dX * cos(rAngle * M_PI/180) + dY * sin(rAngle * M_PI/180);
    float dY1 = -dX * sin(rAngle * M_PI/180) + dY*cos(rAngle * M_PI/180);

    glRotatef(angle,0,0,1);
    glTranslatef(dX1, dY1, 0.0);

Но в таком случае я получаю поведение аналогичное 
   glTranslatef(dX, dY, 0.0);
   glRotatef(angle,0,0,1);

Я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Наверное я ошибся.  Любом случае, чтобы вращать относительно точки необходимо сместить её в центр: glTranslatef(-dX, -dY, 0.0); Потом повернуть glRotatef(angle,0,0,1); Вернуть всё на место: glTranslatef(dX, dY, 0.0); (возможно dX1, dY1) и потом добавить ваше смещение glTranslatef(dX, dY, 0.0); Идея примерно такая.